# JSON data name display

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to display the name and rate of JSON in angular.js

The JSON looks like this :

```
{
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2016-04-15",
  "rates": {
    "AUD": 1.4648,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "BRL": 3.9387,
    "CAD": 1.4535,
    "CHF": 1.0919,
  }
}
```

I displayed rate, but I have problem with displaying the name.
As of now, I only rate displayed. How do I display the name? I'm looking for something like this

**`Name | Rate`**
`AUD  | 1.4648,`
`BGN  | 1.9558,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in rates">
  <td>{{ key }}</td>
  <td>{{ value }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank You so much!

Comment: Your welcome! [Don't forget to accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863). :)